# MAUI Blazor App Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech keyword recognition opening custom table error

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, speech-recognition, maui

I was trying to create simple service that listens for keyword from speech. I was using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech ver 1.24.1 and proceeding with official documentation but got error while trying to read KeywordRecognitionodel from file, file is accessible from that path. Also tried relative and absolute path.

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace HandyCook.Services
{
    internal class KeyWordRecognizerService
    {
    public KeyWordRecognizerService()
    {
        StartRecognizing();
    }

    private async void StartRecognizing()
    {
        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        var recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(audioConfig);
        recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.Result.Text} DETECTED");
        };

        var stream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("XXX.table"); //accessible

        //Exception with an error code: 0x8 (SPXERR_FILE_OPEN_FAILED)
        var keywordModel = KeywordRecognitionModel.FromFile(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "XXX.table"));
        var result = recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync(keywordModel);
        result.Wait();
    }
    }
}
```

To reproduce the error just simply create new MAUI Blazor App, add nuget package 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech 1.24.1', add service as singleton in MauiProgram then inject in Index.razor. I'm pasting also table file and solution explorer view.
[image: Solution explorer view]

table file: https://sendanywhe.re/18U3PXF8